# Why am I getting an error when I try to print the contents of a file I am searching for?

Tags: vb.net, file-io

Can you help me with searching for and printing a file specified by text in `textbox1`? I have the following code but `textbox1` shows me an error. I don't know if the code is correctly written and functioning right.

**First class:**

```
Public Class tisk
    'print 
    Public Shared Function printers()
        Dim printThis
        Dim strDir As String
        Dim strFile As String
        Dim Textbox1 As String



        strDir = "C:\_Montix a.s. - cloud\iMontix\Testy"
        strFile = "C:\_Montix a.s. - cloud\iMontix\Testy\" & Textbox1.text & ".lbe"


        If Not fileexprint.FileExists Then
            MsgBox("Soubor neexistuje")
            printers = False
        Else

            fileprint.PrintThisfile()
            printers = True

        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

**Second class:**

```
Public Class fileprint
    Public Shared Function PrintThisfile()
        Dim formname As Long
        Dim FileName As String

        On Error Resume Next
        Dim X As Long
        X = Shell(formname, "Print", FileName, 0&)
    End Function
End Class
```

**Third class:**

```
Public Class fileexprint
    Public Shared Function FileExists()
        Dim fname As Boolean
        '   Returns TRUE if the file exists
        Dim X As String
        X = Dir(fname)
        If X <> "" Then FileExists = True _
        Else FileExists = False
    End Function
End Class
```

When I fill a textbox with text, how can I search for a file in the computer using this text and print this file?

Comment: What's the error say?

Comment: This looks like VB.Net code written by someone used to VB6. A lot of what's in here used to be good practice when vb6 was current, but is poor code now for VB.Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "Textbox1" is a variable and not actually getting the value from a textbox. If I'm not wrong, I believe you intend to get the value of a textbox and concatenate to form your directory url. You'll first need to add a text box to your windows/web form, give that textbox an id then call that id in your code behind. E.g. You add a text box with id "textbox001", in your code behind you'll do something like "textbox001.text". In your case it'll now be: strFile = "C:_Montix a.s. - cloud\iMontix\Testy\" & textbox001.text & ".lbe". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will fix your issue, but there are some poor practices in that code that are addressed below. This will certainly get you closer than what you have right now.

```
Public Class tisk
    'print 
    Public Shared Function printers(ByVal fileName As String) As Boolean
        Dim basePath As String = "C:\_Montix a.s. - cloud\iMontix\Testy"
        Dim filePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(basePath, fileName & ".lbe")

        If IO.File.Exists(filePath) Then
            fileprint.PrintThisfile(filePath)
            Return True
        End If
        'Don't show a message box here. Do it in the calling code
        Return False
    End Function
End Class

Public Class fileprint
    Public Shared Sub PrintThisfile(ByVal fileName As String)
        'Not sure how well this will work, but it has better chances than the original
        Dim p As New Process()
        p.StartInfo.FileName = fileName
        p.StartInfo.Verb = "Print"
        p.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

One additional comment on the File.Exists() check. It's actually poor practice to check if the file exists here at all. The file system is *volatile*. It's possible for things to change in the short time between when you check and when you try to use the file. In addition, whether the file exists is only *one* thing you need to look at. There's also access permissions and whether the file is locked or in use. The better practice is to *just try to do whatever you need with the file*, and then handle the exception if it fails.